# ValueError: axis(=1) out of bounds while computing the confusion matrix for a pretrained model

Tags: python, numpy, classification

I'm trying to compute the confusion matrix for a pre-trained DL model and the code goes like this: (please don't mind the number of training and validation samples.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import applications
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix
import itertools
from keras.optimizers import SGD

# Plotting the confusion matrix
def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, classes,
                          normalize=False, #if true all values in confusion matrix is between 0 and 1
                          title='Confusion matrix',
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function prints and plots the confusion matrix.
    Normalization can be applied by setting `normalize=True`.
    """
    plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classes)

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    print(cm)
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, cm[i, j],
                 horizontalalignment="center",
                 color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

img_width, img_height = 64,64
top_model_weights_path = 'model.h5'
train_data_dir = 'data4/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data4/validation'
nb_train_samples = 20
nb_validation_samples = 20
epochs = 50
batch_size = 10
def save_bottlebeck_features():
   datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
   model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(64, 64, 3))
   generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
               train_data_dir,
               target_size=(img_width, img_height),
               batch_size=batch_size,
               class_mode='binary',
               shuffle=False)
   bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
               generator, nb_train_samples // batch_size)
   np.save(open('bottleneck_features_train', 'wb'),bottleneck_features_train)

   generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
               validation_data_dir,
               target_size=(img_width, img_height),
               batch_size=batch_size,
               class_mode='binary',
               shuffle=False)
   bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(
               generator, nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
   np.save(open('bottleneck_features_validation', 'wb'),bottleneck_features_validation)

def train_top_model():
   train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train', 'rb'))
   train_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples // 2) + [1] * (nb_train_samples // 2))
   validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation', 'rb'))
   validation_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_validation_samples // 2) + [1] * (nb_validation_samples // 2))
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
   model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
   sgd = SGD(lr=1e-2, decay=0.00271, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False)
   model.compile(optimizer=sgd,
         loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
   model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
          epochs=epochs,
          batch_size=batch_size,
   validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
   model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)
   Y_pred = model.predict(validation_data)
   print(Y_pred)
   y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
   print(y_pred)
   target_names = ['class 0(bt)', 'class 1(cm)']
   print(classification_report(np.argmax(validation_labels,axis=1), y_pred,target_names=target_names))
   print(confusion_matrix(np.argmax(validation_labels,axis=1), y_pred))
   cnf_matrix = (confusion_matrix(np.argmax(validation_labels,axis=1), y_pred))
   np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
   plt.figure()
   # Plot non-normalized confusion matrix
   plot_confusion_matrix(cnf_matrix, classes=target_names,
                      title='Confusion matrix')
   plt.show()
save_bottlebeck_features()
train_top_model()
```

As i run this script, I'm getting the value error for the axis and the full-description of the error is:

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-f618e2626bbb>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/rajaramans2/codes/untitled4.py', wdir='C:/Users/rajaramans2/codes')

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/rajaramans2/codes/untitled4.py", line 116, in <module>
    train_top_model()

  File "C:/Users/rajaramans2/codes/untitled4.py", line 106, in train_top_model
    print(classification_report(np.argmax(validation_labels,axis=1), y_pred,target_names=target_names))

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 963, in argmax
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'argmax', axis=axis, out=out)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 57, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)

ValueError: axis(=1) out of bounds
```

I sincerely hope there is something wrong with declaring the axis in the classification report and confusion matrix. Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: `validation_labels` is a 1d array, so `axis=0` would be the only valid axis. What result were you expecting from the `np.argmax` call?

Comment: Hi Mark, When i tried to declare (axis=0), I get the following error:           File "<ipython-input-16-8eb9e98d6168>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/rajaramans2/codes/untitled7.py', wdir='C:/Users/rajaramans2/codes')
print(classification_report(np.argmax(validation_labels,axis=0),y_pred,target_names=target_names))
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 72, in _check_targets
check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
TypeError: Singleton array 400 cannot be considered a valid collection.

Comment: Do I need to make changes to the file definition for plot_confusion_matrix?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `np.argmax` at all in that call. Doesn't `confusion_matrix(validation_labels, y_pred)` do what you want?

Comment: Hi Mark, Many thanks for your suggestions. I made an error in not converting the y_pred to classes. it remained a class vector since i was using model.predict. validation_labels contains the class labels 0 or 1. I instead used model.predict_classes to convert y_pred to classes so that i can now compute without errors, confusion matrix for the validation_labels and y_pred. Thanks once again.